# Prove convergence in $\Bbb R^m$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

**My attempt:**
First, I have this information:

First, for any $\epsilon_{1}>0$, $\exists N_{1}∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $\left \| x_{n}-a \right \|<\epsilon_{1}, \quad\forall n\geq N_{1}$.

Comment: Your proof is correct, but perhaps missing a bit of detail. The last line says "$\forall n \geq N$." What is $N$? You haven't said. (It's related to the $N_1$ you get from $\epsilon_1=\epsilon/c$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s basically correct, but it could be organized a bit better. In particular, you don’t need different $\epsilon$s and $N$s. Here’s one possibility:

> By hypothesis there is a $c>0$ such that $|\lambda_n|<c$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. Let $\epsilon>0$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$, there is an $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\|x_n\|=\|x_n-0\|<\frac{\epsilon}c$ whenever $n\ge N$. But then $\|\lambda_nx_n\|=|\lambda_n|\|x_n\|<c\cdot\frac{\epsilon}c=\epsilon$ whenever $n\ge N$, so $\lim_{n\to\infty}\lambda_nx_n=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to be aware, when would it be a good idea including two $\epsilon$ or two N?

Comment: @Renzo: You’re welcome! It’s often a judgement call, but the underlying principle is that you want the result to be readable. If you need to talk about two different $\epsilon$s, then you’ll need to introduce two names. Here $\epsilon$ and $\frac{\epsilon}c$ are technically two different ones, but $\frac{\epsilon}c$ is a simple expression, so giving it a new name like $\epsilon_1$ just gives the reader an extra symbol to keep track of when it isn’t really needed for clarity.